# Creating A Shared Global Memory Space Using Threads?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Can this be done?

config.py
- Holds all global variables

state_holder.py
class StateHolder:
- A class that imports all config variables, designed to run on a thread & manage changing of variables.

main.py
- On startup, instantiates StateHolder class, putting all config variables in memory.

module_1.py
- A module that imports main.

module_2.py
- A module that imports main.

I want module_1.py & module_2.py to be able to access the instance of StateHolder instantiated by main.py.  And change/access variables in that instance.

Basically I'm trying to create a shared memory space across all modules of the program.  Any change of a variable in that space by any module is propagated to other modules using that variable.

Can it be done?

Comment: Have you written a POC?  I guess it should work.  Just pay attention to competitor access.

Comment: I tried, and still not got it working as expected.  If I'm trying to do something that can't be done, well, I don't want to waste anymore time.  Is this the way to do this?  Or is there a more elegant solution?  Surely others have had this problem.